# Console print an array of objects with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a method that exports every POJO person and create an array into a JSON:

```
Node temp = testa;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(Paths.get("jPerson.json").toFile(), true);
SequenceWriter seqWriter = mapper.writer().writeValuesAsArray(fileWriter);  

while (temp != null) {
                seqWriter.write(temp.getPersona());
                temp = temp.getSuccessivo();
        }
seqWriter.close();
```

I want to create a method that read every object of the array and print it on the screen. This is the prototype, but it prints the hashcode (Person@6a1aab78, etc.):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
        Persona[] pJson;
        pJson = mapper.readValue(Paths.get("jPersona.json").toFile(), Persona[].class);
        System.out.println(ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(pJson));
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to print the `JsonNode`s or the Java POJOs?

Comment: @Oliver I have a method that simply prints the POJO (Nome: Mark \ Cognome: White \ Birth date: 2/2/1980) and I would like to do something like this.

Comment: Sorry, but I am still unsure. Does my answer help?

Comment: Three community members (including myself) offered you great solutions. I hope you check at least one of them.

Answer (score 1):

`ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(Object)` doesn't create a "deep" `toString` method. In your case you could just call `Arrays.toString(pJson)` and it would have the same result.

Easiest solution is to just override `toString` in `Persona`.

```
public class Persona {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pJson));
```

Or you use a `Stream` to join all the values in the `pJson` array to one `String`.

```
System.out.println('[' + Arrays.stream(pJson)
    .map(ReflectionToStringBuilder::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))+']');
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, but it still prints the hashcode before. ([Persona@8646db9[name=Mike,surname=White,Day=2/2/2000])

Comment: How `ReflectionToStringBuilder` prints the `toString` depends on the `ToStringStyle` you pick. By default it also prints the hashId.

Comment: `return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this,ToStringStyle.JSON_STYLE);` doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing. I would expect it to work, but maybe you are using an old version. If you're import is `org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringStyle` you are using `commons-lang2` which doesn't contain the `JSON_STYLE`. It's a feature added in `commons-lang3`. An alternative that I prefer is lombok which generates `toString` methods for every class that you annotate with `@ToString`.

Comment: This is odd because I'm using common-langs3 and I've imported `org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle;`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `ObjectMapper`.

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    // pretty print
    String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(pJson);
    System.out.println(json);
```

Reference: https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-enable-pretty-print-json-output-jackson/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print your POJO `Persona` as JSON, you can use Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to serialize to a `JsonNode` and use `JsonNode#toString()`:

```java
final Persona persona = ...;
final JsonNode json = objectMapper.readValue(persona, JsonNode.class);

System.out.println(json);
```

If you want to print multiple `Persona` objects, you can iterate:

```java
for(final Persona persona : personas) {
  final JsonNode json = objectMapper.readValue(persona, JsonNode.class);

  System.out.println(json);
}
```

or, even better, serialize once and iterate:

```java
final Persona[] personas = ...;
final JsonNode jsonArray = objectMapper.valueToTree(personas);

// Check may not be necessary.
if(json.isArray()) {
  // JsonNode implements Iterable.
  for(final JsonNode jsonNode : jsonArray) {
    System.out.println(jsonNode);
  }
}
```